# running queries in firebase using async / await

Tags: node.js, firebase, ecmascript-2017

Appreciating that firebase has [added support for promises](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/keeping-our-promises-and-callbacks_76.html), is there a way to run a query like the following inside of an `async` function?:

```
const eventref = this.db.ref('cats/whiskers');
const value = await eventref.once('value')
```

Running the above returns a promise for `value`, I'm hoping to get the json blob that is stored at `cats/whiskers`.

Comment: Yes, why wouldn't it be possible? Have you tried it? Do you have a problem?

Comment: As mentioned, the above returns a promise and not a value.

Comment: Hm, that should not be possible, `await` cannot return thenables. Do you use a transpiler? Have you inspected what the `eventref.once('value')` looks like in a debugger?

Comment: Works for me: https://runkit.com/5906914d3ff14f0012d0307e/590691ab301f4d0012938bc5

Comment: yeah, for some reason I was sticking the `.val()` call in the await statement, this worked for me, too.

Comment: `.once` works but `.on` (so `someRef.on('child_added')`) expects a second argument. Any ideas for that?

Comment: .on don't return a Promise.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The result of `value` is a snapshot, we need 1 more step to get the value. This should be like:

```
const eventref = this.db.ref('cats/whiskers');
const snapshot = await eventref.once('value');
const value = snapshot.val();
```

Comment: Totally saved me!

Comment: What if you need to use the value afterwards, will this tell your code to wait for `value` to be assigned something before proceeding?

Comment: @Badrush for your reference https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#once

Comment: @Badrush `value` event can be used to retrieve the current value of a specific node in your database using `once` or can be used to subscribe to changes on a specific node in your database using `on`.

Comment: What I mean is. Let's say I need to retrieve the snapshot and store it inside of `var A`... then I have a code that takes `var A` and displays it. Is there a way to tell my code to wait until the snapshot is finished retrieving so that `var A` wont be `undefined`?     I do know you can use `.then` but sometimes that makes the code very messy. Especially if `var A` isn't used until much later in the code.

Comment: @Badrush you can just use await:  `var A =  await eventref.once('value');` because what you're talking about is exactly what `await` do.

Comment: Thank you. Will it still continue processing code that doesn't require `var A` in this example?

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal just wrap the block in try-catch