# How to run a firebase function correctly?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This function will return the value of `initiate_session, initiate_session[user_session].events, user_session`
before the firebase function runs.

How to run the firebase function first ??

```
function createSession() {
var user_session = randomCharacters(20) //8iKhA4Aq2!6gZ)890ip@;
var ip = '127.0.0.1';
var initiate_session = new Object();
var session_started = new Date().getTime();


firebase.database().ref(user_session).once('value', function (snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
        console.log('session exists');
        createSession();
    } else {
        console.log('session not exists')

        initiate_session[user_session] = {
            ip: ip,
            session_started: session_started,
            events: {}
        };

        firebase.database().ref(user_session).set({
            ip: ip,
            session_started: session_started,
            events: {}
        });
    }
});

console.log('new session', initiate_session);
return [initiate_session, initiate_session[user_session].events, user_session];}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because the Firebase function is asynchronous - the code inside the method that gets the snapshot is a **callback** that is executed after the Firebase read is finished, which may take several seconds. However, as soon as you dispatch the read request via `.once(...)` your execution flow continues and the return is called.

There are a few possible solutions:

1. Pass a callback argument to your `createSession()` method that is called with the values you are trying to return, instead of returning them directly.
2. Return a promise from your method that resolves to give the values you're trying to return.
3. Use `async`/`await` syntax for your Firebase call. This is covered already in this question: [running queries in firebase using async / await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43712720/running-queries-in-firebase-using-async-await)

**Rough Example of #1**

```
function createSession(onSessionCreated) {
    var user_session = "whatever";
    var initiate_session = new Object();

    firebase.database().ref(user_session).once('value', function (snapshot) {
        // do things with the snapshot
        onSessionCreated(initiate_session, initiate_session[user_session].events, user_session)
    });
}

// usage:
createSession(function (initiate_session, events, user_session) {
    // do things with initiate_session, events and user_session
});
```

**Rough Example of #2**

```
function createSession() {
    var user_session = "whatever";
    var initiate_session = new Object();

    firebase.database().ref(user_session).once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
        // do things with the snapshot
        return [initiate_session, initiate_session[user_session].events, user_session];
    });
}

// usage:
createSession().then(function (results) {
    // do things with results (i.e. the three elements in the array above)
});
```

**Rough Example of 3**

```
async function createSession() {
    var user_session = "whatever";
    var initiate_session = new Object();

    const snapshot = await firebase.database().ref(user_session).once('value');
    // do things with the snapshot

    return [initiate_session, initiate_session[user_session].events, user_session];
}

// usage:
const results = await createSession();
```

---

If you're new to `async`/`await` code it probably won't be the easiest place to start as it may require changes elsewhere in your code, but [this article](https://javascript.info/async-await) is a good resource if you're keen to learn.

Comment: `const results = await createSession();` await should be inside async?

Comment: Yes, that would need to be inside an `async` section.

Comment: `const session = await createSession();`


`async function createSession() {
    var user_session = randomCharacters(20) //8iKhA4Aq2!6gZ)890ip@;
    var ip = '127.0.0.1';
    var initiate_session = new Object();
    var session_started = new Date().getTime();

    var snapshot = await firebase.database().ref(user_session).once('value');

   //Some codes
    return [initiate_session, initiate_session[user_session].events, user_session];

}`


result: `Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`

Comment: @AbdulaziAlswaji As I said, using the `async`/`await` patter might require changes elsewhere in your codebase, so it probably won't be the easiest solution if you're not using `async` code already. Solutions #1 and #2 will require fewer changes to existing code, so you might want to start with one of them.