# async await in nested firebase database query

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, async-await

am trying path an html container from firebase,. all data should be stack according, this is my code:

```
firebase.database().ref('message/' + user.uid).on('value', function (snap) {

    console.log('at the first position');
    firebase.database().ref('chat/today').on('value', function (message) {
        console.log('at the second position');

        firebase.database().ref('day/tuesday').on('value', function (snap) {
            console.log('at the third position');

            firebase.database().ref('scores/' + user.uid).on('value', function (snap) {
                console.log('at the fourth position');
            });


            console.log('at the fifth position');


            firebase.database().ref('user/friends').on('value', function (snap) {
                console.log('at the six position');
            });

            console.log('at the seventh position');;
        });

        console.log('at the eight position');
    });
    console.log('at the nineth position');
});
```

I want to know if I use `async / wait` on all `firebase.database()` calls would it run synchronously?

I am expecting this console output:

```
//at the first position
//at the second position
//at the third position
//at the fourth position
//at the fifth position
//at the six position
//at the seventh position
//at the eight position
//at the nineth position
```

but am getting this :

```
//at the first position
//at the nineth position
//at the second position
//at the eight position
//at the third position
//at the fifth position
//at the seventh position
//at the fourth position
//at the six position
```

Comment: Yes, using await will make this code no-longer nested and "synchronous". Why not try it first? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47713500/5734311

Comment: You almost certainly want to use once() instead of on() to perform single queries.

Comment: @Chris G, by using>>> const eventref = const snapshot = await eventref.once('value') ; won`t this assignment need to be wrap in an async function?

Comment: Yes, you can use await only inside async functions.

Comment: thanks alots, it works but i must wrap all inner functions in one parent async function to keep the flow going